# get value of text clicked on from dynamic table and pass to servelet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

In a jsp file i create a dynamic table based on the users invoices or purchases. I create the table with no problems. The issues is, i href the first field(invoice number) of the row and want to display a form with detailed information on that particular invoice number. 
The form pops up on the same screen, with a close button to go back to the list and click another invoice number.
How can i pass the invoice number, based on the invoice number the user clicks to the servelet and populate the href form?

This is the html to create the table:

```
    <table class="tableinvoice" >
            <tr>
            <th scope="col" >Invoice number</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            </tr>
        <tbody>     
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="#form" id='formid'> <%= ls.get(0) %> </a></td>
            <td> <%= ls.get(1) %></td>
        </tr>               
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the form the html on the same jsp:

```
 <div id="form" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="content">
       *****invoice information here***
    </div>
</div>
```

Any other suggestions to accomplish this are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the invoice number in data attribute

```
<a class="invoice-link" href="#form" id='formid' data-inv="1223">
```

Then simple ajax to get data and open modal:

```
$('.invoice-link').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var $link = $(this),  
         $form_modal = $( $link.attr('href') ),
         inv = $link.data('inv'),
         api_url = '/path/to/server/' + inv;

     // use `$.ajax` shorthand method to retrieve html
     // or use `$.getJSON` and a template
     $form_modal.find('.content').load(api_url, function(){
          // html from server exists now
          // run the modal open code here
          $form_modal.modalScriptOpen()
     });
});
```

Comment: how will i get the inv value to pass to the servelet? the servelet code is in java.

Comment: doesn't matter what language is used on server. This is a standarg GET request. Use whatever convention you need to construct the url